# Can you create a file in two locations

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a simple interface, using a database poll that creates a text file based on a simple orchestration.

the file is output to an FTP folder and is picked up by our client. now every so often we have a client that claims a file was not send or data was incomplete in the file, but since they have removed the output file from FTP we have no copy of this file.

i thought about creating two send ports in the orchestration so i can create a file to the FTP and an archive folder. problem with that is that the file name is DELSUP%datetime%.txt, so this will result in my backup file having a slightly different name. is there a way to make a send port create a backup-file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you just need to set up a new send port and configure it to send a file of your preferred name.  You can use the same message as your FTP port. HTH

Comment: but won't this give the file a slightly diffrent timestamp name? i suppose if thats the bestway, i can live with one file being DELSUP201207101128 and the other DELSUP201207101129, but this might make communicating with the client harder since the datetime will be slightly diffrent

Comment: Why not copy the first timestamp to a variable and then insert it in your 'backup'

Answer (score 3):

Use a **SendPortGroup** instead of a single SendPort.

Enlist the original FTP SendPort as well as a new FILE SendPort in a SendPortGroup, then change your Orchestration configuration to bind to the new **SendPortGroup** rather than the FTP SendPort.

Comment: would using these create the excact same file? if you use message_ID will it be the same?

Comment: It will be a different file name, even though both messages appear to have the same MessageID in the Message Box.  I have confirmed this with a simple proof of concept adding two identical send ports to one SendPortGroup, resulting in 2 files with differing names in the output directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the %SourceFileName% macro in the file adapter properties:

[image]

In your case you would not need to to do anything else as the adapter will read the filename from the message context property `FILE.ReceivedFileName` and then set preserve the filename end to end.